# Unable to initialize kotlin class member from secondary function

Tags: kotlin

```kotlin
class Person constructor(val first_name: String){
    init{
        println("Welcome, ${first_name}")
    }
    val last_name: String
    constructor(fname: String, lname: String): this(fname){
        this.last_name = lname
    }
    fun fullNameGreeting(){
        println("Welcome, ${first_name} ${last_name}")
    }
}

fun main() {
   val kotlin = ""
   println(kotlin)
   val adam: Person = Person("Adam", "Kim")
}
```

I get following error in Kotlin Playground:-

- Property must be initialized or be abstract
- Val cannot be reassigned

I am just trying it after reading the documentation on Kotlin website. I am still learning but I am not able to solve this problem. Please Help.

Comment: The question you need to ask is: **What does `last_name` get set to if you call the primary constructor directly?** (Answer: it doesn't get set to anything. And that's why the compiler is complaining.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Property must be initialized or be abstract:

You got this error because you didn't initialize a value to `last_name`, you can't just declare the name and the type of the variable, you need to assign a default value to it like that `val last_name: String = ""`

- Val cannot be reassigned:

And for this error because you set `last_name` as a value by using `val` and that means that you can't change it anymore, but you are trying to change it here `this.last_name = lname`, so to be able to change `last_name` you need to set is a variable by using `var`, like that `var last_name: String = ""`

So your final code should look like this:

```
class Person constructor(val first_name: String){
    init{
        println("Welcome, ${first_name}")
    }
    var last_name: String = ""
    constructor(fname: String, lname: String): this(fname){
        this.last_name = lname
    }
    fun fullNameGreeting(){
        println("Welcome, ${first_name} ${last_name}")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val kotlin = ""
    println(kotlin)
    val adam: Person = Person("Adam", "Kim")
}
```

If you want to create an instance of Person with only first_name or both first_name and last_name, you can use this approach:

```
class Person constructor(
    val first_name: String, 
    val last_name: String = ""
){
    init{
        println("Welcome, ${first_name}")
    }
    
    fun fullNameGreeting(){
        println("Welcome, ${first_name} ${last_name}")
    }
}
```

This way you can either call `Person("Your first name")`, or `Person("Your first name", "Your last name")`

Comment: So this means I can't use constants member with secondary constructors? like I have used with primary constructor.

Comment: You can but it's quite different in kotlin, I will add how you can achieve that

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest switching the constructors around. Then you can do

```
class Person constructor(val first_name: String, val last_name: String){
    init{
        println("Welcome, ${first_name}")
    }
    
    constructor(fname: String): this(fname, "")

    fun fullNameGreeting(){
        println("Welcome, ${first_name} ${last_name}")
    }
}
```

or better yet, make the second parameter optional, like

```
class Person constructor(val first_name: String, val last_name: String = ""){
    init{
        println("Welcome, ${first_name}")
    }

    fun fullNameGreeting(){
        println("Welcome, ${first_name} ${last_name}")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `val` is used for constant and `var` for variable (overwritable) properties. If you replace `val`s in the class with `var`s, it works.